# How do I map pixels to a coordinate system?

Tags: coordinate-systems

As often happens I'm not sure of the name of what I'm trying to do, so I'm having difficulty searching it. I know this is basic algebra, but my math is null so I'm struggling with it greatly.

I have a coordinate system that starts from 0,0 in the bottom left corner, and ends in 1,1 in the top right corner. I must "translate" from coordinates to pixels and viceversa. I'm including a diagram to clarify what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to do this with Javascript, but I guess it's irrelevant. A formula is enough to get me started.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: bottom left pixels should read "5, 195", sorry.

Comment: should it read 1,0 in the bottom right or top left? (instead of 0,1, which appears twice)

Comment: Ugh, true, uploaded fixed image.

Comment: An interesting related issue for you may what pixels correspond to the points on a particular straight line. One approach to this is known as Bresenham's Algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your coordinates look odd, but going from co-ordinates to pixels, you probably want something like 
$$f(x,y) = (190y+5,195-190x)$$
and going from pixels to coordinates 
$$g(a,b) = \left(\frac{195-b}{190},\frac{a-5}{190},\right)$$
but you may need to adjust this slightly to deal with what happens on the edges

Comment: Thanks! But the y axis is inverted, how do I account for that?

Comment: I have edited my reply

Comment: Thanks! I've implemented it and it's working perfectly.